# wallpaper rotation with xelatex

Tags: xetex, pdf, rotating, pandoc, wallpaper

I am using the wallpaper package in a tex template to generate pdfs with pandoc.

The tex template is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
  \setmainfont[]{Junicode}
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\hypersetup{
  hidelinks,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\ThisULCornerWallPaper{1}{letterhead.pdf}
\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \newgeometry{top=2in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in}  
        \afterpage{\aftergroup\restoregeometry}
        $body$
    \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

pandoc command is:

```
pandoc test.md -r markdown --template=letterhead.tex --pdf-engine=xelatex -o test.pdf
```

The output file has the wallpaper image in landscape format, rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise and scaled to fit the x-dimension. Why does this happen?

When I convert the wallpaper source to a jpg and update my template file to read

```
\ThisULCornerWallPaper{1}{letterhead.jpg}
```

the output file generated by XeLateX has the correct orientation and scaling, solving my problem.

When I use LaTex as pdf engine (rather than XeLateX), the template works as expected with both wallpaper source formats, pdf and jpg.

That is, the unexpected rotation only occurs with a pdf wallpaper source and XeLateX as pdf engine.

I am using XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please -- as usual here -- make your code snippets compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ... Have you considered to update your system (only if you have no deadline soon!)?

Comment: Do you have any news for us?

Comment: @Mensch Thanks for following up. I'm very new to this so please tell me if my edit isn't yet up to standards.